# How to load an img tag in webView in Android?

Tags: android, html, webview, android-webview, android-websettings

I want to load the following HTML code in the Android webview.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body style = "text-align:center">

<img src="http://XXXXXXXX.com/books_snaps/UR335/1.jpg" alt="pageNo" 

height="100%" width="100%"> 

</body>
</html>
```

where `http://XXXXXXXX.com/books_snaps/UR335/1.jpg` is a image link. I want to load this image in `<img>` tag of above HTML. How can I embed above HTML code in webview of Android?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
String htmlString = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body style = \"text-align:center\"><img src=\"http://shiaislamicbooks.com/books_snaps/UR335/1.jpg\" alt=\"pageNo\" height=\"100%\" width=\"100%\"></body></html>";
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,htmlString,"text/html","UTF-8","about:blank");
```

Also, you need to add the internet permission,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: thanks for such quick rply. But image is not appearing in my browser. its showing the "alt" text that is pageNo (alt=\"pageNo\")

Comment: Yes. i forget to to set INTERNET permission in my menifest file. thanks. Upvote +1 :)

Comment: Thnx bro it is really help me

Comment: Waah.. kavi nicely explained.

Answer (score 1):

you can first save the html file in assets folder say

```
assets\html\index.html
```

then just load the Page to webview as

```
   webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/index.html");
```

or you can try this

```
String content = 
       "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>"+
       "<html><head>"+
       "<meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" />"+
       "<head><body>";

content += myContent + "</body></html>";

WebView WebView1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
WebView1.loadData(content, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 1):

Following Sanket Kachhela answer, if you run your app on Android 9.0 device, and still don't see the images, consider adding `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to Application tag in the Manifest file.

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    ...
```

For me it did the job.

[See this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50834600/2826184)

Answer (score 0):

You can download that image from the link and then you need to create a folder named "Images" into your android application assests folder.

And then after you can change the path of your image link to `../images/1.jpg` in your html file.

Try out this way. I am sure it will work.

Thanks.